# Error en recursividad en C++

Tags: c++, recursión

Mi objetivo es el siguiente: ingresar por teclado 2 números(A y B) distintos a 0, y con A mayor a B, debo determinar cuantas veces cabe B en A, mediante uso de una función recursiva. Sin embargo, lo que realice funciona con **A=6** y **B=2** en el que el programa me devuelve que *"2 cabe 3 veces en 6"*, pero si ingreso **A=8** y **B=7** me devuelve que *"7 cabe 7 veces en 8"* en esta ocasión en vez de devolverme 1 me devuelve un 7. No estoy encontrando la solución a este problema. Mi código es el siguiente:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<conio.h>

int Division (int A,int B)
{
    int div;
    if(A<=B)
    {
        return 1;
    }
    else
        {
            return A - Division(A-B,B);
        }
}

main()
{
    int A=8,B=18,div;
    while(A<B || A<=0 || B<=0)
    {
        printf("Ingrese un valor para A que sea positivo y un valor para B menor al valor de A\n");
        printf("Valor de A: ");
        scanf("%d", &A);
        printf("Valor de B: ");
        scanf("%d", &B);
        system("cls");
        
        if(A<B || A<=0 || B<=0)
        {
            printf("No se cumplio las condiciones de A y B, ingrese nuevamente valores validos");
            system("pause");
            system("cls");
        }
    }
    div=Division(A,B);
    printf("%d cabe %d veces en %d\n",B,div,A);
    system("pause");
}
```

¿Cuál es el error que estoy cometiendo?

Comment: Esto no es [tag:c++], la función `main` no tiene tipo de retorno, todas las cabeceras que incluyes son de [tag:c] y todas las funciones que usas son de [tag:c].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Centrémonos primero en tu caso de prueba fallida:

A=8 y B=7 , Resultado=1. Esto lo que indica es que tu función recursiva debe de ingresar solo una vez, posterior retornar 0.

lo mismo sucede en el primer caso:

A=6 y B=2 , Resultado=3. Esto lo que indica es que tu función recursiva debe de ingresar tres veces, posterior retornar 0.

Entonces, como tu función recursiva en ningun momento suma las iteraciones no re aliza su trabajo. Una solución posible seria:

```
int Division (int A,int B)
{
    if(A<B)
    {
        return 0;
    }
    else
    {
        return 1 + Division(A-B,B);
    }
}
```

Puedes ver el funcionamiento en este fiddle --> http://cpp.sh/4wpfw

Podriamos ahorrarnos algunas lineas si eliminamos el `else`:

```
int Division (int A,int B)
{
    if(A<B)
    {
        return 0;
    }
        return 1 + Division( A-B , B );
}
```